# How to assign php template to generated url?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a form in a php file:

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/results/">
    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Enter height">
    <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Enter weight">
    <input type="submit" id="export">
</form>
```

That generates a random url when clicked (like *mydomain.com/gLd3a*) using `jQuery`:

```
$("#export").click(function(){
    url = $("#form").attr("action");
    url = url.replace("/results/","/<?php echo $randomString ?>/");
    $("#form").attr("action", url).submit();
});
```

But I'm trying to automatically make the generated url show content from a php template (*results.php*).

I tried to do that using the `action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/results/"` but `/results/` is being replaced by the random string, therefore has no effect.

Is there any other way to assign that php to the generated url please?

Comment: what I understood from your question, that you want to submit the form to results.php and load its content some where in your page, right? if not, please explain what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I am submitting a form. that form then takes you to a new page with a randomly generated url (like mydomain.com/abcdefg or mydomain.com/b1kfhg). I need the results.php to load its content on that random url. Please tell me if still not clear sir

Comment: Thank you for edit @arman1991, sorry for the bad English

Comment: I still cannot find solution, but I try many different htaccess rule and think that maybe the best way?